# Characteristic Function Comprehesnion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, characteristic-functions

*I am having trouble wrapping my head around characteristic functions. I'm not the best when it comes to taking theoretical explanations and then applying it to an actual problem. I'm a hand's-on learner and really need to see something and repeat the steps myself to really grasp wtf I'm even doing. Really what I need is a super dumbed down walk-through. So if anyone can help me with the following, I would be appreciative. (Keep in mind this IS a homework assignment and I would much rather learn what's going on than just be shown an answer because that doesn't help me.)*

---

Define $f: \Bbb R → \{0,1\}$ as the characteristic function of $\Bbb Z+$, the set of positive integers. That is, $f(x) = \chi_{A}(x)$, for the set $A$ of positive integers $= \{ n | n \in \Bbb Z+ \}$.

Answer the following questions using the definition of $f$ given above. Your answers for (b) and (c) should each be a set. You may specify each set by listing the values, using set builder notation, or describing the set in words.

a) Draw the graph of the function $f(x)$ for $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.

b) What is $f(\{x \mid −1 < x < 4\}$? That is, what set is the image of the set of values between $-1$ and $4$? Explain.

c) What is $f^{-1}( \{x \mid 2 < x < 5 \}$? That is, what set is the preimage of the set of values between $2$ and $5$? Explain.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're struggling with? Maybe this will help: The value $f(x)$ of the characteristic function is $1$ if $x$ is a positive integer and $0$ if $x$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: Do you understand that $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is a positive integer, and $f(x)=0$ for all other real numbers? The graph in (a), for instance, will be all of the $x$-axis between $-2$ and $2$ **except** at $x=1$ and $x=2$; at those values of $x$ the graph consists of the points $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$.

Comment: It is just a function which says whether or not a point is in the set (1) or not (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if $A$ is any set, then $\chi_{A}(x)$ is the function defined by $$\chi_{A}(x) = \begin{cases}  1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x \not \in A \end{cases}. $$

For example, take the set $A = \{1,5\}$ of two elements.  Then if we let the domain of the function $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(x)$ be the reals $\Bbb R$, we have:

$\chi_{\{1,5\}}(1) = 1$, $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(\pi) = 0$, $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(2.16) = 0$, $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(5) = 1$, $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(10000) = 0$.

$\chi_{\{1,5\}}(x)$ equals $1$ only if $x$ is in the set $\{1,5\}$, i.e., only if the input $x$ is either $1$ or $5$.  For any other input other than $1$ or $5$, $\chi_{\{1,5\}}(x)$ outputs $0$.

In your case, $A = \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$.

So $\chi_{\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}}(x)$ is the function that equals $1$ when the input is in the set $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and equals $0$ otherwise.  From this description, I think it should be easy for you to draw this function's graph.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a function so that
$\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \textrm{if}\,\, x \in A\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$

It's pretty much just "indicating" when $x$ is in a set.

$\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}(x)$ is $1$ if $x$ is an integer, and zero otherwise.

So, for the first problem: $\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is zero if $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_+$. What are $\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}(0)$ or $\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}(.5)$, for example? What is the image of $\chi_{\mathbb Z}([-2,2])$? Well, definitely $0$ for all $x \neq 1,2$, and by definition $1$ for $x=1,2$.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.

We're saying that 0,1 are in a set and if x is a positive integer of that set then f(x)=1 but if the number isn't part of the set f(x)=0? So for −2≤x≤2 it would be 0, 0, 1, 1, 0?

Comment: @Partshark Close.  First of all, $x$ can be any real number, not just an integer.  It can be a decimal, or even an irrational number.  But you are right.  For the real numbers $x$ that satisfy $-2\leq x \leq 2$, only the positive integers make $f$ equal to $1$.  So $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 1$.  The other integers in that set, which are $0$, $-1$, and $-2$, are not positive integers.  So $f$ of each of those is $0$.  And also $f$ of any real number between $-2$ and $2$ that is not equal to $1$ or $2$ makes $f$ equal to $0$.  So $f(0.1) = 0$ for example.

Comment: Alright so I assume the graph for this would be a horizontal line @ y=0 for all real numbers between x=-2 and x=2 with a break for a horizontal line @ y=1 between x=0 and x=1.

Comment: @Partshark Yes! Except not at $x = 0$, since $0$ isn't a *positive* integer.  You would have a break at $x=1$ and $x=2$.  But not in between them.  So basically draw the line $y=0$, but leave 2 holes: one at $x=1$ and one at $x=2$.  Put a dot above each of those holes at $y=1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how image/preimage works in this case. Would the image then be $f(a)=\{0,1\}$?

And would the preimage be an empty set?

Comment: A set containing a single element in the domain can have only one element in its image, this is part of the definition for a function

Comment: If you take the characteristic function for some set $A $, then the preimage of $1$ will be exactly $A $ and the preimage for $0$ will be the complement of $A$. There are only two points in the image of $\mathbb R $, because the characteristic function maps to only two values, namely $0,1$.

Comment: The preimage of any $a \in \mathbb R/\{0,1\} $ will indeed be empty.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I understand this now. (^_^ )y